# Handling 302 in angular $http

Tags: angularjs, w3c

I make a $http request to my server . I get a response of 302 which hits the failure callback with valid data . Should I handle the 302 response in failure ( I know thats not even close to clean way of doing it)and mark the data as valid if I do so what will be the consequences or just handle it on server.

Answer (score 0):

302 is not the success code thats why it hits failure callback. I think you need to handle it in backend. You can refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to understand  the meanings of status codes.